# ObjectListView aspect name as other object property

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I am new to ObjectListView and I haven't found how to use a property of a object inside the model as AspectName for ObjectListView.

For example, the list will show Cars names and their owner name

```
public class Person
{
    private string _name;


    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => _name = value;
    }
}

public class Car
{
    private Person _owner;
    private string _name;

    public Person Owner
    {
        get => _owner;
        set => _owner = value;
    }

    public string Name
    {
       get => _name;
       set => _name = value;
    }

}
```

If I set the AspectName of a column to Owner.Name it doesn't show anything on the list. I have made a small workaround of defining a property OwnerName inside the Car model, but I have more complex models which is a pain to have to define that property.

Is there a way I can do that?

Thanks

Comment: Owner is "private". Declare it public and it should work.

Comment: @Rev1.0   Sorry, Here is a simpler model of what the object in my application is, and I forgot to put the Owner property public. In the model of the application Owner is public. How can I put it Name property in the ObjectListView?. Thanks

Comment: Jason's answer is fine, but you can also do dereferencing using just the `AspectName`. So "Owner.Name" will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you have said then this should work.  So there must be some other problem which is causing this issue.

You could try setting the AspectGetter programmatically instead such as this;

```
this.olvColumn2.AspectGetter = delegate (Object obj) 
{
    Car car = (Car)obj;
    if (car == null)
        return "Unknown";
    else
    return car.Owner.Name;
};
```

You can then put a breakpoint inside this code and see when/if it is called and what happens.

Remember that you must define/set all of the aspect getters etc. before you call `objectListView1.SetObjects`